# Posterior predictive checking for Bernoulli distributed data

Tags: bayesian, model-selection, markov-chain-montecarlo, posterior, stan

I am fitting a logistic regression model with 6 continuous response variables (6 coefficients + intercept) and a binary response variable $y$ in `rstan` for $N$ observations. After setting my actual model and defining the priors for the vector of coefficients $\beta$, I also use a `generated quantities` block to calculate a vector $y^{rep}$ of the same length of my response vector $y$, drawing from a `bernoulli_logit_rng` with the probability of success defined by the product of my observed data and the model coefficients, for each observation.

```
generated quantities{
  vector[N] y_rep;

  for (n in 1:N) {
    y_rep[n] = bernoulli_logit_rng(X[n]* beta);
  }
}
```

My current understanding is that, for each MCMC iteration, a random draw will be produced with the current coefficient values for that iteration, for each observation. As an example, if I have 1000 post-warmup draws, I will have a matrix of size $1000 \times N$, where each column will contain all the Bernoulli draws for that observation generated through the 1000 MCMC iterations.

However, I am not really sure on how to use this information to perform a posterior predictive check: first, I thought that I could check each column of the matrix, and choose a final outcome for each $y^{rep}_i, i \in 1, \ldots, N$ by selecting the most common class in the 1000 draws. In this way, I will have one final outcome (either $y^{rep}_i = 1$ or $y^{rep}_i=0$). 
Then if the distribution of this vector of final outcomes $y^{'rep}$is similar to my observed $y$, then it is an indication that the model is adequate. I checked this on my data and saw that there was a 98% accuracy between the correspondence of $y$ and $y^{'rep}$.

[Gelman et al. (2014)](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book/) mention on p.143 that:

> If the model fits, then replicated data generated under the model
>   should look similar to observed data. To put it another way, the
>   observed data should look plausible under the posterior predictive
>   distribution. This is really a self-consistency check: an observed
>   discrepancy can be due to model misfit or chance.

From this, I understand that they mean that each $y^{rep}_i$ should look similar to the corresponding $y_i$. Then, they say:

> Our basic technique for checking the fit of a model to data is to draw
>   simulated values from the joint posterior predictive distribution of
>   replicated data and compare these samples to the observed data. Any
>   systematic differences between the simulations and the data indicate
>   potential failings of the model.

I am not sure I get this last idea: does this mean that I should draw randomly from my matrix of $y^{rep}$ values and expect the proportion of 0/1 to be similar to my observed $y$? I have also done this for my data: I sampled 10000 values from the matrix of $y^{rep}$ values and see that the proportion of 0/1 is almost identical to the proportion in my observed data $y$.

My question is: what is the correct way to perform the posterior predictive check?

Comment: This is a great question. What was your final decision (if possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't try to pick a single y_rep_i value for each i but actually look at full distributions or summaries of the distributions. To that end, check out the bayesplot package (also from the Stan Development Team) which has a lot of functionality for PPCs and several vignettes that cover some of these concepts and provide examples. You can also get good help at Stan the forum  (http://discourse.mc-stan.org)